# Split List based on index of value

Tags: python

Assuming I have a list of dates:

```
dates =['11/09/2013','12/09/2013','20/09/2013','27/09/2013','30/09/2013']
test = '21/09/2013'
```

I want to split the 'dates' list based on this 'test' variable

Desired output:

```
1. ['11/09/2013','12/09/2013','20/09/2013']
2. ['27/09/2013','30/09/2013']
```

If 'test' actually belongs(contains) in the list, it must be in list 1.

I'm trying everything still no luck.

Comment: turn them all into datetime objectss, sort/filter them?

Comment: you've tried **everything** what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert the strings into datetime objects and then split the list using a date comparison:

```
from datetime import datetime
dates =['11/09/2013','12/09/2013','20/09/2013','27/09/2013','30/09/2013']
test = '21/09/2013'

# Convert to datetime objects
dd = [datetime.strptime(d,'%d/%m/%Y') for d in dates]
tt = datetime.strptime(test,'%d/%m/%Y')

# Split lists
dd_before = [d for d in dd if d < tt]
dd_after = [d for d in dd if d >= tt]

# Convert back to strings if needed
dates_before = [datetime.strftime(d,'%d/%m/%Y') for d in dd_before]
dates_after = [datetime.strftime(d,'%d/%m/%Y') for d in dd_after]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about converting the items to datetime objects?

```
from datetime import datetime

# convert to datetime objects
datesdt = [datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y') for date in dates]
testdt = datetime.strptime(test, '%d/%m/%Y')

# make separate datetime object lists for low and high dates
low_date_dt_list = [dt for dt in datesdt if dt <= testdt]
high_date_dt_list = [dt for dt in datesdt if dt > testdt] 

# now print in desired format
low_date_list = [dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') for dt in low_date_dt_list]
high_date_list = [dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') for dt in high_date_dt_list]
```

Here's what I get for output when using the above code with your given `dates` and `test` values:

```
In [27]: low_date_list
Out[27]: ['11/09/2013', '12/09/2013', '20/09/2013']

In [28]: high_date_list
Out[28]: ['27/09/2013', '30/09/2013']
```

- [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) for `datetime.strptime`
- [Datetime Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)
- [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) for `strftime`

Answer (score 0):

```
dates =['11/09/2013','12/09/2013','20/09/2013','27/09/2013','30/09/2013']
test = '21/09/2013'

dates.append(test)
dates.sort()
index = dates.index(test)
print dates[:index]
print dates[index + 1:]
```

output

```
['11/09/2013', '12/09/2013', '20/09/2013']
['27/09/2013', '30/09/2013']
```

You can get your desired result.

Comment: Sorting dates in day/month/year format lexicographically is dangerous.  It only worked here because all the moths and years were the same..